# How to use NLP to parse naturally written commands?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nlp, nlp-compromise

I am fairly new to NLP in general. My goal is to create some kind of parser that can easily find files on my various hard drives. 
I have no idea how to properly parse the input to transform it into any managable representation that a program can easily use to create a given output.

For example, the following sentences should return a list of documents:

1. `documents created 3 months ago`
2. `documents modified 2 weeks ago`
3. `photos taken in china` (this one would then use the GPS data within the image file)

It can probably be easily done using some kind of Regex pattern (`<filetype> <action> <time>`) but I would love to make it more flexible.

I looked into [compromise](https://github.com/spencermountain/compromise/wiki/Projects), a JS library that has some easy to use API to retrieve specific parts of the input. But I kind of doubt that calling methods like `calculatedResult.nouns()[0]` and `calculatedResult.verbs()[0].stem()` should be used to parse the commands as those require a fixed kind of syntax.

Any tips on how to achieve my goal? I am not sure if using ML and training a custom model is the way to go. I never use ML and, based on my low knowledge of it, it seems kind of hard to train it constructs like those (as I would need a LOT of example sentences but there is just a finite amount of realisically used combinations that make sense).

Answer (score 1):

The NLP technique you need to explore is **intent detection**. You can either integrate a NLP library like RASA or Spacy into your program or work with a commercial API that conducts intent detection. You will need example sentences in both cases but probably not as many as you think. Intent detection is a key part of chatbots so there's quite a lot of tools out there. Low level, hands-ons ML development is not really needed these days with all the high level intent detection tools out there.